# close MessageComposeViewController after send message swift

Tags: swift, xcode

When click on the button, a window opens for sending a message, the problem is that the window that opens does not close after sending a message, just after clicking on the cancel button ... always have to kill the application.

```
 @IBAction func smssendOrderButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {


      let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
    controller.messageComposeDelegate = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
    self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)

    controller.body = orderBody()
    controller.recipients = ["89883003000"]

    func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                  didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
  controller.messageComposeDelegate = self as? controller.messageComposeDelegate = self as? MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

With:

```
   class Vc: UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate { 

@IBAction func smssendOrderButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {

  let controller = MFMessageComposeViewController()
  controller.messageComposeDelegate = self

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, `MFMessageComposeViewController` delegate method is written within `smssendOrderButtonTapped` method.

You will have to confirm to the `MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate` protocol and implement following;

```
class 'YourViewController': UIViewController, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {

func messageComposeViewController(controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                              didFinishWithResult result: MessageComposeResult) {

controller.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

}
```